# Why Google search is not up-to-date in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

Was trying to pair android emulator with android wearable.

I created an AVD(Nexus 5 skin) using Google API with Lollipop 5.0.1, Google Services is running 7.3 on that emulator, but Google search function is so out dated, it even has the 2.3 theme in it and wearable needs a much higher version. 
what a shame!

[image: android wearable companion]
[image: the Google search from the emulator]

Am I doing anything wrong here? I have tried to pair emulators using genymotion, after install ARM translation and Google services, the Android Wearable Companion just keep crashing.

If there is a good post out there please share, thanks!